# How to print lines start with same number in one line using python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to print the lines starts with same number in one line using print function in python. But I coudl not do it. I have looked for similar questions I did not find. 
My data looks as follows

```
0 17 12 CA
0 3 14 CB
1 5 15 CC
1 6 16 CD
1 7 18 CE
```

Like this I have large data with lines started with same number
I want to print as below
output :

```
0 17 12 CA 0 3 14 CB
1 5 15 CC 1 6 16 CD 1 7 18 CE
```

Comment: Are you looking into this because they are being printed in separate lines? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = [
    "0 17 12 CA",
    "0 3 14 CB",
    "1 5 15 CC",
    "1 6 16 CD",
    "1 7 18 CE",
]
identical = {}
for l in lines:
    index = l.split()[0]  # find starting characters (before first whitespace)
    identical[index] = " ".join( # use join to concatenate strings with appropriate whitespaces
        (
         identical.get(index, ""), # get existing string, "" if no existing string
         l # add the new line to the end of the existing string for current index
        )
    ) 
print("\n".join(list(identical.values())))
```

Gives:

```
0 17 12 CA 0 3 14 CB
1 5 15 CC 1 6 16 CD 1 7 18 CE
```